# deploy mvc2 application in IIS7 in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to deploy my MVC2 application on the IIS7 of my Windows Server 2008 R2 to allow non-developpers to test it.
I deployed through webdeploy, it didn't work.
I just copied the files after a build, didn't work.
I copied the published file, didn't worked...

When I click on the web site link in my IIS, nothing append.

I don't know what I am doing wrong..
Somebody could help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can give some more details on what happens when you try to browse to the site on the server (do you get a yellow screen exception, 404 error, etc) it will help to identify the cause. Without knowing more details, here are some suggestions:

If you don't have MVC 2 installed on your server (which is not a requirement), make sure you are doing the following:

- In your Visual Studio project, under References, make sure you set the "Copy Local" property to "True" for System.Web.Mvc. This will deploy the dll to your site bin dir when you do a web deploy.
- Make sure the .NET Framework version 4 is installed on the server. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en) for more details.
- In IIS, make sure the Application Pool that the site is using is set to use v4.0 of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Actually, like I said, nothing appends. I already test this thing. The address correspond to nothing...

Comment: Actually I'm not sure to do it well... Can someone explain me step by step how to do? My application is in MVC2 (4.0). Whatever the method to deploy, I really need to deloy fast and well! Thanks in advance!